# Was Chris Shiherlis cheating on his wife?

Tags: heat

Rewatched a scene in Heat (1995), where McCauley was having a conversation with Shiherlis the morning after Chris and his wife had a fight. McCauley then brought up the possibility of Charlene cheating on Chris and Chris cheating on Charlene. Look, I know enough English to know that Chris was convinced that his wife is not the type to have an affair, but what Shiherlis said in his dialogue with McCauley really confused me.

> McCauley: You got something else on the side?
>
> **Shiherlis: Nothing regular**
>
> McCauley : She got something on the side?
>
> Shiherlis: No

Was Chris implying that he had an affair, hence his reply, or were they referring to something else entirely?

Comment: I would need to rewatch the scene, but I think this was referring to him losing everything in Vegas. McCauley asked something like "Not even after all we've been doing?" and the reply was "Vegas wiped me out."

Comment: McCauley is obviously referring to either of them being unfaithful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP:

> *Was Chris implying that he had an affair, hence his reply, or were they referring to something else entirely?*

Chris actually states his situation:

- He is not having an affair (a regular - an affair is on on-going attachment with dates and a person or persons met with more than once, perhaps on a semi-regular basis; there is an on-going relationship established)
- He does have irregular contact with others that are not his partner (not stated as sexual, but likely, given his other vice and where he does it; there is no relationship established)

The dialogue:

> McCauley: You got something else on the side?
>
> Chris: Nothing regular

He is not having an affair, just casual hook ups - one-nighters, hookers, etc

While it is not implicitly portrayed in the film, that sort of answer is often  one given to casual sexual meetups, probably also tied in with the gambling and casinos (he mentions Vegas also cleans him out), the sort that has no emotional attachment and is done with in the morning after.

In his eyes that sort of dalliance is not serious and would never take him away from Charlene and his son, with whom he has definite emotional attachment (in a later scene for example, he asks for her when in recovery from his wounds).

> McCauley : She got something on the side?
>
> Chris: No

Neil checks Chris' answer:

> Neil McCauley : You sure?
>
> Chris Shiherlis : Yeah I'm sure

He is convinced that his wife is faithful and has no suspicions.

He is also content in that he only has casual flings, and will not separate from Charlene:

> Chris Shiherlis : For me the sun rises and sets with her, man.

Note:

Even technically outside of the marriage partnership, Chris sees a clear difference between having an affair and having irregular hook ups.

Charlene by comparison is clearly having a proper full-on affair.

But, as per OP's title, was Chris cheating on his wife? Then yes.

Comment: On pages 23/24 of the script, it's implied that they met in some place Chris is still visiting once in a while in Vegas (or elsewhere) . Charlene (to Chris): "*Where's the club you were going to open? [...] Shut up! I left for a good thing. [...] I'm married to you, now. This isn't the fucking joint.*" (to me, a joint is just another type of speakeasy, with booze and 'ladies', correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Yes, a joint is that. So from that conversation, Chris cannot stop being a regular at the joint that he originally met Charlene at. But *that does not imply that the women he has hook ups with are the same one(s).* When she says she 'left' - to me that implies that she was staff, something like a waitress.

Comment: "Heat 2" (Michael Mann's recently released book) is part prequel: https://screenrant.com/heat-2-novel-heat-movie-character-fates-sequel/ : "it details how Chris and wife Charlene first met in Vegas, where she was a sex worker and they had an instant spark"

Comment: "The storyline then shifts back to 1988. We get to see parallel stories of the criminal crew, this time in Las Vegas, and Hanna, who is working in Chicago. Shiherlis, a known degenerate gambler, meets Charlene, who at that time is a high-end call girl. They instantly fall in love, and he vows to take her away from the life she’s been living." https://www.bookreporter.com/reviews/heat-2

Comment: Well, you have me at a disadvantage, I never even knew there was a book release. I was even guessing that he was seeing prostitutes. My initial guess was that the hook ups were girls hanging on to the gamblers. 'Heat 2' shines light on their meeting, but still, she is having an affair and he is.. technically..(by his standards) not...

Comment: Supposedly he also talks about the back stories in this podcast: https://www.theringer.com/2021/11/2/22758064/the-three-heat-with-bill-simmons-chris-ryan-and-michael-mann

Comment: Thanks for the updated info. Not sure it needed a sequel book though. Great fan of the film.

Comment: @OldPadawan - implies his vice is not just gambling, but also prostitutes. The background info supplied in Heat 2 obviously confirms that. Is seeing prostitutes (but not a particular one, on a regular basis, that we know of) the same as having an affair? I think Chris sees a difference.

Comment: one-shot? I thought you could **cough** have multiple. i think. I've heard..

Comment: I'm too old to remember what we were talking about...